# How can I export photos from lightroom CC with filenames ordered by capture date / timestamp?

Tags: lightroom, export

I often have shoots where I bring two cameras to one event, so when i afterwards export the files they are by default sorted by how the two cams name the files. This is not so nice when viewing the images, since the event won't be displayed to the enduser in a chronological fashion. Therefore I'd like to export files in a way, such that when viewing on any OS, you can simply click "order alphabetically by filename" and the viewer gets the shots in a chronological manner.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Put your images in an album and order your images by capture date in Lightroom CC

[image]

Step 2: Select all your images

Step 3: Click on export (Custom, not the preset ones)

[image]

Step 4: Choose a custom filename

[image]

Your images will be exported in the right order as a sequence.

[image]

Comment: Surely there is a way to rename the files based on shooting date/time without suffering the degradation of exporting a jpeg to another jpeg? It's easy enough with Canon's DPP 4 to use the bulk file rename tool.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the files from card into Lightroom, in the import settings you can copy and rename the file and add date and time in front of the original file name. This should help with organization.